# Changing the integration equation in NDSolve upon an event

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I'm trying to implement the solution to the following ODE

dx/dt = -x for x < 0

dx/dt = x for x > 0

Using `NDSolve` and `WhenEvent`, how can I do this?

Comment: Is it even possible for x to change signs given this equation?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Nuno! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `Sign[x]`.

```
Plot[Sign[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
nds = NDSolve[{D[x[t], t] == Sign[x[t]]*x[t], x[-1] == -2}, 
   x[t], {t, -1, 1}][[1, 1]];
Plot[x[t] /. nds, {t, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-2, 0}]
```

yields

[image]

Instead of the `Sign[x]` you may want to use a smooth function, such as `Tanh[x/0.1]`.

```
Plot[Tanh[x/0.1], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]
Then the solution

```
nds2 = NDSolve[{D[x[t], t] == Tanh[x[t]/0.1]*x[t], x[-1] == -2}, 
    x[t], {t, -1, 1}][[1, 1]];
Plot[x[t] /. nds2, {t, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-2, 0}]
```

is practically the same:

[image]

Have fun!